# How to render a formula through Mathjax when it's called on the Javascript and I want to output the values of variables?

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml, mathjax

Some time ago I coded an [in-browser fraction calculator](https://456p6z.mimo.run/index.html) and now I decided to use Mathjax in order to render the output in a more visually pleasant fashion. The problem is the formulas to be outputted depend on the values of variables and I don't know how to do this.

For instance, a snippet of the original code is:

```
return "The fraction " + x + "/" + y + " is irreducible. ";
```

where x and y are parameters of a function. I tried something like:

```
return "The fraction " + "$${"+x+ "\over" +y+"}$$"+ " is irreducible . ";
```

but it outputs the word "over" and the "$", "{", "}" symbols rather than rendering a fraction.

Reading the [pertinent documentation](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.4-latest/typeset.html), I got that outputting a Mathjax formula after the page is loaded is not trivial and some commands are required in order to render them. So I threw the commands

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
MathJax.Hub.Typeset();
```

on the functions, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Backslashes have special meaning in Javascript strings (they are used to get non-ASCII characters like `\n` for a newline and `\t` for a tab).  So if you want to include an explicit backslash in your string (as you do here), you need to double it (`\\`).  That means you need to use `"\\over"` in place of `"\over"`.

Comment: Thanks! It still didn't solve the problem, but I bet it's part of the solution. Now, rather than outputing "The fraction $${1 over 2}$$ is irreducible", it's outputting "The fraction $${1\over 2}$$ is irreducible".

Comment: Now you need to add `MathJax.Hub.Queue["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]` after you add the math to the page.